# Jquery email validation seems to get ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm trying to do is:

Have the user input an email. If it's not valid; show the error. If it's a valid email, have the `.wizard` div slide up and display a message 'Cool'!

As of right now my code ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/HvjtB/30/)) isn't cutting it. It doesn't seem to add the `.error` class to the input, nor having the `.wizard` div show. What am I doing wrong? Another set of eyes would greatly be appreciated.

```
 $(".wizard").hide();
 $("#signup").show();

$(".continue").click(function () {
    var valid = true;
    $("#" + $(this).attr("validationDiv")).find("input").each(function () {
        if (!/^S+@S+.S+$/.test($this).val()) valid = false; // if its not a valid email
            ($this).addClass('error'); // show error
            ($this).val('Please Insert a valid Email');          
    });
    if (valid) { // if it is valid
         $(".wizard").slideUp(); // have this div show
         $("#" + $(this).attr("data-next-id")).slideDown();
     }
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: what's not working? in my case, nothing happened when entering a non-email address and a valid email address

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation. Right now: the error message(when it's an incorrect email) and the .wizard(to show when it is a correct email) div doesnt show. I'd like to know why and how I could fix it. :)

Comment: there is no div with id `signup` as given in `validationDiv`, though there is one `signUp`

Comment: couple problems : 1. you're selecting an ID, when `signUp` is a class. 2. the attribute validationDiv's value is `signup`, when it should be `signUp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a lot of careless mistakes

```
$(".wizard").hide();
$("#signup").show();

$(".continue").click(function() {
    var valid = true;
    var that = this;
    $("#" + $(this).attr("validationDiv")).find("input").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
                if (!/^S+@S+.S+$/.test($(this).val()))
                    valid = false;
                ($this).addClass('error');
                ($this).val('Please Insert a valid Email');
            });
    if (valid) {
        $(".wizard").slideUp();
        $("#" + $(that).attr("data-next-id")).slideDown();
    }
});
```

demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HvjtB/31/)

Problems I found
1. There is no element with id `signup` as indicated by `validationDiv` attribute, so add `id="signup"` to the top div(`class="sighUp"`)
2. In the inner callback you have used `$this` many times, but it was never defined, solve it by `var $this = $(this);`

Answer (score 1):

First thing, you should really be learning jQuery and javascript before...

`$this` should be `$(this)`. And you mixup `classed/id`, plus you don't use the correct elements name. No wonder it's not working. Here is a corrected example: http://jsfiddle.net/HvjtB/28/

Now you just need to create a correct email detection Regexp: http://www.regexper.com/

Answer (score 0):

You're sliding the Wizard up when you really should be sliding it down.